# set numbers sum about average point

Tags: algorithm

I've got vector **f** of numbers [2 5 7 1 4 3] and I would like to create **n** threads which should have **free amount of** numbers 'around' main vector. Let's assume **n** is 2

```
2 + 5 + 7 + 1 + 4 + 3 = 22 / n = 11
```

So i need to create pair of:

```
[7 4] because it's 11
[2 5 3 1] because it's 11 (or near eleven)
```

is it possible to avoid such as algorithm:

1. Make all possible combination of vector **f** (with length from 2 to 6)
2. filter all generated combination to find **n** which sum is around to 11

I'm asking because I have to start **x** tasks(threads) with **y** jobs to do. Each job should be **rerun** after defined for this job time (time of job which we will need to end this job is estimated in this main vector **f**)

could you advice me something?

Comment: If it's possible, then, I think, it's not known for now. Your problem is extension of [3SUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) well-known issue - and that can be resolved in subquadratic time at best.

Comment: What language are you using? If it is not a programming question, I think you should consider some other forum.

Comment: c# is my programming language

Comment: @Alma Do, doing it exactly as in 3SUM might be hard, but often heuristics can given an approximate solution quickly.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this depends on how exactly you want to answer this, and on the distribution of the numbers. E.g., if the distribution is usually nearly uniform over an interval, then sorting the list and picking out every number will work fairly well.

e.g. here {1,2,3,4,5,7} are your numbers sorted, so take {1,3,5} & {2,4,7}. If the number of elements divides exactly by the number of groups, then taking the first and last numbers is even better. E.g. if n=3 take {1,7}{2,5}{3,4}.

None of these heuristics will work well if the numbers are {1,10,100,1000,10000}. (i.e. exponentially distributed).

If you tell us a little more about the distribution of the numbers you expect there is a good chance that someone can produce a reasonable heuristic.

From your question, it seems a bit like these numbers are related to the run time of the threads, so you want to divide the work evenly between a number of threads. if that is the case then this is not the right solution - use an executor service with a fixed thread pool and a priority queue, which prioritises the longest running tasks highly, in that case it always starts the longest remaining tasks, and this will usually ensure that all threads finish roughly together.

Comment: I've got problem to construct algorithm which will implement all my assumptions.

1. n threads
2. each tests take some time and should be run with defined for this test interval
3. there is highly possiblity that threads count < tests

that's why i tried reorder task (i think there is some inconsistency in second and third point)